# Xcode 12 - Project Navigator width is stuck/locked, can't resize

Tags: xcode, xcode12

Every so often the project navigator/left panel is stuck at a fixed width. This is very annoying when I have extensions in separate files named `MainViewController+<Extension name>`, because the `<Extension name>` is truncated.

[image: Can't resize project navigator]

<sup>*PhotoSlide... what???*</sup>

Pressing the "Hide or show the Navigator" button doesn't do anything either.

[image: Press expand button in top left]

Quitting Xcode and restarting works. But this takes time, and I lose my place. Is there any other way to fix the stuck width problem?

Comment: i tried the same case but it is already working for me. Xcode 12.3

Comment: @zeytin yeah usually it works. I think it only glitches when I switch between monitors or something, but I come across this a couple times every day

Comment: I found that this happens when I don't resize the Navigator after opening a project and then only after a period of time. If I open a project and then immediately expand the Navigator, it greatly reduces the occurrence. It doesn't happen immediately, there seems to be a timeout threshold when the bug manifests itself. This explains why it passed their automated testing, but wow, they have had 4 releases and its still not fixed.

Comment: This seems to be related to the debugger as that's when my locking starts to occur. Really wish there was a better solution than the accepted answer.

Comment: I see the same issue here. @Senseful's solution did work for me. Btw, is this an Xcode bug?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Instead of opening a new window, just use a tab:

1. Open a new tab (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>)
2. Close the old one

Comment: [Paul Solt also said this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65851619/xcode-12-project-navigator-width-is-stuck-locked-cant-resize/67028721#comment118416439_65851620), but thanks for posting it as an answer! It works better than opening a new window

Comment: I submitted a Feedback issue: (Please duplicate) "Xcode Project Navigator Panel Gets Stuck at a Specific Size and Wont Resize" FB9071658

Answer (score 20):

Please follow these steps if you don't want to reopen the Xcode everytime:

1. Right-click (or control-click) on any file
2. Select <kbd>Open in New Window</kbd>
3. And ta-da! You can now resize the project navigator freely!

[image: Performing the above steps]

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't fix the window that's already open. Hoping for a better solution or a fix from Apple.

Comment: How did you discover this?

Comment: @Akif pretty much completely by chance. I like to open files in a new window so that I can switch back and forth quickly. And one time, I noticed that the newly opened window could be freely resized :)

Comment: Use `Command + T` to open a new tab, you should be able to resize in the new tab, and close the other tab.

Comment: I submitted a Feedback issue: (Please duplicate) "Xcode Project Navigator Panel Gets Stuck at a Specific Size and Wont Resize" FB9071658

Comment: @PaulSolt that works very well. Post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

This also annoyed me....finally I clicked around and found the show/hide navigator icon on the very top left next to the os icons and clicked it...after that it could resize.

it is to the left of the play button fyi.

Answer (score 1):

I have had success by re-sizing the entire Xcode window - make it smaller then larger and the navigator becomes resizable again.

Answer (score 1):

Sad to say it, but restarting Xcode worked for me..

Comment: OP said: "Quitting Xcode and restarting works. But this takes time, and I lose my place. Is there any other way to fix the stuck width problem?"

Answer (score 1):

Here is another workaround. When the navigator gets stuck or locked, click on the "Debug" navigator (or View > Navigators > Debug menu item). Voilà, you now should have the ability to resize.

NOTE: You may have to do this a couple times by selecting another navigator or two and then re-selecting the debug navigator.

UPDATE: This doesn't work reliably. @Senseful has the [best solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67028721/403801) so far.

[image]